VBA Not showing word formatting for complex script words
I have a Word document having this text:
Some bold some not bold
18. तत्र चेतनालक्षणो जीव:

इनमें-से जीवका लक्षण चेतना है

I have this VBA code to figure out which words are bold or not.
    For Each s In ActiveDocument.Words
    
    If s.Bold = True Then
        MsgBox s
    End If
Next

Now the issue is it only shows English words as bold in message box (in this sample - "Some bold"). It does not detect the other words as bold in document. Interestingly it does not even show number 18 as bold though it detects it as separate word.
I am wondering if there is any way to figure out these words are bold programmatically. This is just a sample. I have a big file to do some programming.
Please help. Thanks

Message Boxes only display ASCII characters. Your problematic content does not consist of ASCII characters. I suspect the 18 is an automatic number, which is why if isn't found. In any event, a looping VBA Find would be far faster than looping through each and every word.

With Word 2007 (yes, old, but still from this millenia) I get the result you hope for, that is the following words are listed: Some, bold, 18, ., तत्र, चेतनालक्षणो, जीव, :, 18. The last 18 is from the paragraph "Now the issue ...." But I have no idea why it wouldn't work for you, or what you could do to get it working.

@macropod From where do you read that message boxes only display ASCII characters? I don't see anything like that in the MS documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function]

Maybe you should try it. Simply copy & paste the इनमें-से जीवका लक्षण चेतना है into a new document, then select pasted content and try to output the selected range to a message box via MsgBox Selection.Text. All you'll get is: ?????-?? ????? ????? ????? ??

@macropod As you can see in my first comment, I already tried it with the code of OP.

Odd, I see the same as @macropod, the same is stated in this answer

What gets displayed in a MsgBox is related (somehow) to the Windows System locale and probably the System Display language, i.e. to locales. Even if the font set up as the Message Box font in Windows (used o be much easier to change before Win10) supports all the characters you want to display, the system locale/display choices still determine/influence what appears as a "?". AFAIK the main point is that if you want something to display in a MsgBox regardless of locale selections, use ASCII (or perhaps it's more like the Unicode characters up to U+00FE or some such)

Another possibility is that you have applied a bold font to the Devanagari text, rather than applying bold formatting to a regular Devanagari font. If that's a possibility, you would have to look at the font names (and possibly even the font characteristics, which would probably require some WIN32 calls) as well as the state of the .Bold property of the word.

The problem is not with MsgBox. The ultimate goal is to use that bold/non-bold text for some formatting. MsgBox is a way to test for me what would I get as bold content in this document. So the real issue is Word VBA is not giving bold text as bold when it is mixed up with complex script like Devnagari in this case.

@jonsson, This helped a bit. I removed the formatting of the texts, applied the same font again, applied bold property. Then running the code is giving expected results. If that would be solution, I would have to re-format the whole document. I am not seeing an option to attach the word file if any one would be interested to see difference in file formatting..

To post an actual file you have to use an online service - AFAIK StackOverflow does not provide that. If you need to change the font for your Devanagari text, you may be able to do it with a few Advanced Find/Replace operations where you look for one font, replace by another, and apply bold.
